# Is it a good idea to let database surrogate key values spill out into other aspects of code (HTML, Controllers, Model, Repository layer)?

Tags: object-oriented, mvc, coding-standards, repository, surrogate-keys

Is it acceptable to use `id` in HTML forms and subsequent code processing (controller, view, model, repository layers)?

For example I need to show something like this on a web page:

```
Select Motor Choice:
* 460/50/3
* 380/50/3
* 460/60/3
```

In HTML this can be done with a `radio` control, where each line has a `value` attribute, which is not shown, and `text`, which is shown on the screen.

I have above encoded in the database like so:

```
id, motor_description
1, "460/50/3"
2, "380/50/3"
3, "460/60/3"
```

I can use the `id` for the `value` in HTML `radio` control, and i can use that `id` internally as well in my Controller where I process the input to do lookup on the motor.

But since `id` is a surrogate key, and it doesn't mean anything, will I do better instead to avoid using it, and instead to perhaps use more user-meaningful information, such as the `motor_description` field to look up the data in the table and do other processing related to my business needs?

My concern here is ... even though I am using surrogate key *in the database table*, do I continue using it as well in *the rest of my application*, or is it best to avoid doing so?

In other words, do I let the database's surrogate key "spill out" into other aspects of my code, or do I avoid doing so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You need a unique Id for these things and the DB id fits the role.

Ideally the unique id is independent of the database though. Have a GUID on your business object and use that as the DB key rather than the other way around. But 99.9% of the time its going to be a purely conceptual difference.

Answer (score 1):

Using surrogate keys outside of a database is fine if

- those keys are 100% immutable and are guaranteed to never change afterwards (since you typically cannot update them in external systems)
- even though those keys get more visibility this way, you can restrain any stakeholders from inventing new "business requirements" for these keys (like "lets use a magic ID 9999 for a motor template")
- the value of those IDs does not provide internal information to the outside world you don't want to show anyone (like a number which lets competitors see how many offers or orders of a certain kind your company gets per month)